# How to call a django method from template without using a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, django-templates

I'm building a comment system and want to implement upvoting/downvoting, similar to SO and reddit. My question is, how exactly can I detect a click on my upvote or downvote `img` and call a function from django? Or is there another way of going about this? Here's my code:

**template**

```
...

<div class="vote_div">
   <img src="upvote.png" class="upvote" />
   <img src="downvote.png" class="downvote" />
</div>

...
```

**models.py**

```
class Comments(models.Model):

    ...

    #score
    upvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I want to call a function in my views.py to handle the voting, but as I said I don't know how to do it. As i'm aware it's not possible to call a django function from js/jquery. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to answer your question, but first you are really going about this a bit wrong. The way you've structured this there isn't a good way to police how many times a person votes. Even if people never deliberately game this, there will be inevitable goofs that cause people to vote for a thing multiple times.

Ideally, set up a second table like this (assumes you are only polling logged in users):

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("User")
    comment = models.ForeignKey("Comments")
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Then you would have a button that submits a simple one field form view with +1 or -1. The "score" would be a simple sum or you could count positive and negative values to get a value for how many upvotes or downvotes there are.

If this is an app of any significance you should use a REST api (I like [Tastypie](https://github.com/django-tastypie/django-tastypie) but there are others). It's a bit of a slog getting the first API down, but not too bad and it's worth investing in unless your app is dead simple.

So finally... the dead simple hack/bonehead way to do this. You don't need a form, just use a [generic View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/intro/)

Add this to urls.py with a url like normal with comment_id as a kwarg

```
url(r'^vote/(?P<comment_id>\d+)/$', BoneheadView.as_view(), name='comments-vote'),
```

In views.py:

```
class BoneheadView(View):
    def post(self, comment_id):
        if "vote" in self.request.POST:
            vote = int(self.request.POST["vote"])
            if vote_score in (-1, 0, 1):
                # Do something to save your vote here like:
                (vote,created) = Vote.objects.get_or_create(comment_id=comment_id)
                vote.score = vote_score
                vate.save()
                return HttpResponse("Yay, a Vote")
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Invalid Vote", status=400)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid Vote", status=400)
```

Finally, on your page:
Revised HTML

```
<div class="vote_div">
   <a href="{% url 'comments-vote' comment.id %}" data-score="1" class="vote"><img src="upvote.png" /></a>
   <a href="{% url 'comments-vote' comment.id %}" data-score="-1" class="vote"><img src="downvote.png" /></a>
</div>
```

(Put this right before `</body>` on your page)

```
<script>
$(".vote").click(function() {
    var element = $(this); // grab the object that triggered the event
    $.post(element.attr('href'), { score: element.data('score')});
    return false;
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about nesting the `img` in an `a` tag so that should work. As for the models, i'm not too familiar with ForeignKey but i've looked up the documentation and I can't find `ForeignKeyField`. Did you mean to write ForeignKey or is that a different syntax? Also what does a REST API do that I can't already? Or what does it make easier specifically?

Comment: It's ForeignKey... that's what happens when you code from memory and don't have a code checker. If you are just doing one or two little things like this, a REST API is probably overkill, but it's a good idea to get in the habit of doing the "Right Thing". A REST API lets you build a lot more functionality and is more structured and standardized. The more functionality you build into your mixed javascript/ django app, the more you will appreciate having a standardized way of exchanging data between the two.